# Java: Best style in clearing collections

Tags: java

Lets assume I have a language with garbage-collection (e.g. Java).

```
for (...)
{
  List <String> lst = new ...
  // do something with lst
  // lst not longer needed for this pass of the loop

  lst.clear ();   
}
```

The clear () at the end of the loops body is not necesarry. lst will get initiated new in the next pass. The memory will also get freed by the GC.

But is it better style to do the clear or to skip it?

Comment: Did you try benchmarking both the approaches ?

Comment: We're only considering a list of strings, not a list of things that might be referenced elsewhere?

Comment: No. I am asking for style, performance not so much. I think style is most of the time more important than performance.

Comment: @chris01, if you are looking for style, then just clear it.
Also if your for loop ends, the last list will be cleared then...
EDIT: MY BAD the list is IN SCOPE, so no need to clear it

Comment: Purely for style: don't clear it. Considering performance as well: don't clear it (all the data becomes unreachable anyway, so you are just spending time setting things to null).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is fair to say: adding that call to `clear()` is bad practice.

It is simple: you strive to write the minimum amount of code that does what you need in the most expressive way you can think of.

Thus: you avoid to put down anything that is meaningless!

A `clear()` for a collection that isn't used afterwards is exactly that: meaningless. And besides having a performance impact at runtime it might easily confuse your readers! "Heck, he is clearing that thing, why is that?"

Rule number 1 in programming: don't write code that surprises your readers.

Comment: this only is true if the list is in scope of the for loop. If you want a cleared list after your for loop, when you instatiate the list outside of the loop. then it would be good to clear it. This way you dont have any "left-overs" in your list from the last loop

Comment: @DigitalJedi that is in the question, though. If the list existed in a broader scope, clearing or not becomes a question of correctness, which is a fundamentally different issue.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call the `list.clear()` at the end of the loop, because if it is created inside of the loop, after that iteration it will die. Objects created inside of a method or block are Die-young, they will be eligible for garbage collection right away. If you call the list.clear() method, it will add overhead and unnecessary complexity to the code.

Comment: you are confusing _scope_ with _reachability_

Answer (score 1):

The general advice in cases like this is - skip it, unless you really have a problem with this: proven by a profiler.

Just notice that whatever you have in your List is going to be alive for as long as the List itself is alive; because it's strongly references it's entries.

What you are showing is a method scoped List and that is an entire different story and calling `ArrayList::clean` for such a case seems useless to me in the majority of cases.

You should also understand that that local-method `List` can *still* be GC-ed, reachability and scope are *different* things.

Answer (score 0):

I used a WeakReference queue to track hard references and watch when they were gc'd.

I found that the fastest way to gc a list of elements is to assign it the value of `null` and invoke the garbage collector.  This appeared to be true for a list created inside a method or block and it happened immediately. Without doing both, the waiting method didn't finish (I only gave it a few minutes) If you're worried about exhausting heap space you might consider soft references.

Interesting side note:  When I did this with Integers instead of strings, I created Integer objects from 0 to N_ELEMENTS.  All but the low 128 were "garbage collected."  I attribute this to the fact that Integer values from 0 thru 127 are interned according to the Java specification so a hard ref still exists.

```java
import java.lang.ref.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GCTest {
   ReferenceQueue<Object>      rq         = new ReferenceQueue<>();
   List<WeakReference<String>> wkrefs     = new ArrayList<>();
   static int                  N_ELEMENTS = 1_000_000;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new GCTest().start();
   }

   public void start() {
      List<String> hardRefStrings = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int j = 0; j < N_ELEMENTS; j++) {
         String v = new String("abcdefg");
         hardRefStrings.add(v);
         WeakReference<String> myWeakInt = new WeakReference<>(v, rq);
         wkrefs.add(myWeakInt);
      }

//    hardRefStrings = null;  // uncomment this
      waitForCollection();
   }

   public void waitForCollection() {

//    System.gc();  // uncomment this

      System.out.println("Waiting for garbage collection");
      long lastcount = 0;
      while (lastcount != N_ELEMENTS) {
         long count = wkrefs.stream().map(WeakReference::get).filter(
               a -> a == null).count();
         if (lastcount != count) {
            lastcount = count;
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Done");

   }
}
```

Comment: this is a good answer IMO, 1+. I would not use `String v = new String("abcdefg");`, but instead a plain `new Object()` for simplicity. also that `System.gc();` does not mean that a GC _will_ be triggered, it's just a hint after all. Also note that clearing a WeakReference is an async process, there is a timeframe after the GC and posting that event to the ReferenceQueue.

Comment: I figure they would be gc'd eventually, but for some reason (which I can't explain), assigning null to the list **and** invoking the gc visibly sped up the process.  This is on Windows 10.

Comment: what do you mean speed up the process?

Comment: The wait loop finished immediately vs kept running.  As I said, I only gave it a few minutes.  But something about assigning null to the list object and invoking the gc had some effect which I can't explain.

Comment: that might be pure coincidence... but either way, there is no explicit timeframe documented anywhere, so "it depends" on the GC, Env, phases of the moon, etc...